Is there a way to enable email notifications for a created Share URI
Context:
I've managed to create a ShareFile URI using Create Share API for user downloads of a specified file (using https://api.sharefile.com/docs/resource?name=Shares). A user is able to download an ShareFile item using the ShareFile URI.
With the web UI, there is a setting: Share > Get a link > Edit options > Notifications > Notify me when this link is accessed When checked, this would email download activity to the account associated email.
Issue:
Is there a parameter that can enable email notifications similar to the ShareFile Web UI? Or some way to enable email notifications for downloads for a generated ShareFile URI?
I've tried a few combinations of the provided parameters but none of them resulted in email notifications when a file was downloaded using the generated ShareFile Link. Have looked through ShareFile documentation but am not able to find anything. This is the current payload being used:
    "generate_share_url": {
    "type": "POST",
    "payload": lambda items: {
        "ShareType": "Send",
        "Items": items,
        "RequireLogin": False,
        "RequireUserInfo": True,
        "MaxDownloads": -1,
        "ExpirationDays": 30,
    },
    "payload_type": "json",
}

